# arraylist with custom objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a very basic question. I am trying to read values of three EditText fields and save them as one item in an arraylist using an arrayadapter. My question is how can I group the three variables I read from the EditTexts and add them as a single item in the arraylist?

Answer (score 13):

```
class editTextString{
private String  str1
private String  str2
private String  str3

public editTextString(String data1,String data2,String data3){

str1 = data1;
str2 = data2;
str3 = data3;
}

}
```

now add this class to ArrayList..

just like below,

```
ArrayList<editTextString> list = new ArrayList<editTextString>();

editTextString data = new editTextString("edit1","edit2","edit3")

list.add(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom object that holds the strings from 3 edittexts

And the array list can be

```
public class CustomObj{
    String str1;
    String str2;
    String str3;

    public CustomObj(String s1,String s2,String s3){
        this.str1 = s1;
        this.str2 = s2;
        this.str3 = s3;
    }
}


ArrayList<CustomObj> customObjList = new ArrayList<CustomObj>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyObject {
    private String string1;
    private String string2;
    private String string3;

    public MyObject(String s1,String s2,String s3) {
        string1 = s1;
        string2 = s2;
        string3 = s3;
    }

    public toString() {
        return string1 + " " + string 2 + " " +string3;// your string representation
    }
}


MyObject[] adapterList = new MyObect[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.add(edtxt1.getText()+edtxt2.getText()+edtxt3.getText())
```

this will stored in the adapter