# Using Custom Classes With LinkedList - Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to create a LinkedList of a custom class.

I've stripped my code back and followed the suggestion here:

[arraylist with custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607899/arraylist-with-custom-objects)

When I run the code and debug it, I can see that the LinkedList number of elements is increasing with each add, but all the data is 'sitting' in the first index, with the later elements all empty.

```
public class editTextString {
        private String  str1;
        private String  str2;
        private String  str3;

        public editTextString(String data1,String data2,String data3){

        str1 = data1;
        str2 = data2;
        str3 = data3;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<editTextString> list = new ArrayList<editTextString>();
    editTextString data = new editTextString("edit1","edit2","edit3");
    list.add(data);
    list.add(data);
    list.add(data);
}
```

Expected output:
List to have 3 elements each with three substrings within.
Actual output:
List with 3 elements, first contains three substrings, next two are empty.

Comment: Please show a complete example. As each of the elements in your list is the *same object* it isn't possible for the first to have three strings, and the next two to be empty.

Comment: How you know that "next two are empty." ? (For example, is the output of printing `list.get(1).str1`?)